# Fortran-style multidimensional arrays in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, fortran

Is there a C++ library which provides Fortran-style multidimensional arrays with support for slicing, passing as procedural parameter and decent documentation? I've looked into [blitz++](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/) but its dead!

Comment: Take a look at [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).  There appear to be [facilities](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_views) in there providing what you describe.  I've never used them though, so I can't be sure.

Comment: seems,it is almost compatible with my description except support for array slicing,i'm just wondering can i cast my std :: aray  into this array as required for 1D case.

Comment: Slicing support is there, through views.

Comment: @Xeo yeah but that looks a bit weird!

Answer (score 2):

I highly suggest [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/):

> Armadillo is a C++ linear algebra library (matrix maths) aiming towards a good balance between speed and ease of use

It is a C++ template library:

> A delayed evaluation approach is employed (at compile-time) to combine several operations into one and reduce (or eliminate) the need for temporaries; this is automatically accomplished through template meta-programming

A simple example from the web page:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    arma::mat A = arma::randu<arma::mat>(4,5);
    arma::mat B = arma::randu<arma::mat>(4,5);

    std::cout << A*B.t() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running OSX the you can use the vDSP libs for free.

If you want to deploy on windows targets then either license the intel equivalents (MKL) or I think that the AMD vector math libs (ACML) are free.

Comment: I appreciate,but my requirement is slightly different fortran-like mult-array, not linear algebra package. And i use Linux , LAPACK,ATLAS and BLAS are already pre-packaged (netlib version)

Comment: Ah, sorry man. I played with Blitz++ a long time ago. What is wrong with it now apart from lack of development? Happy hunting and all the best.